# How to configure VirtualBox guest to have internet access?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine

VirtualBox allows different configurations for network access from guest to host. I am on:

- Host: Windows 7
- Guest: Ubuntu 14, 32-bit

Then, checking network access:

- Host (ipconfig) says: Ethernet adapter LAN, Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host
- Guest (ifconfig) says: eth0 and lo

I tried different combinations to let both machines talk. Especially, I need internet access on the guest to run apt-get, ...

a) On VirtualBox, there --> settings --> network --> attached to
      I tried NAT, NAT network, bridged adapter, internal network, host-only adapter, ... no luck to get an IP and/or get apt-get update to work

b) On VirtualBox, there is --> preferences --> proxy or network (nat networks or host-only networks)
      unclear if/how this might influence the network setup

Anyone has experience debugging this? Oh, and host is behind a proxy example.com:123

UPDATE: Bridged Mode boots into a VM and ifconfig returns an IP address - still no traffice to the internet with apt-get update

[image]
[image: ifconfig_bridged_output]

Comment: I would recommend reading up on the differences between the networking options VirtualBox provides here: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html. It will be easier to find a solution to your problem once you know which type of network connection you need for your VM. Chances are you either want NAT or Bridged.

Comment: Are you getting an ip address on the guest in any of the configurations? Depending on which ubuntu install media you used your interface might not be enabled by default.

Comment: Bridged always worked for me right out of the box.  Although this was at least 2 years ago. Bridged mode makes the VM (almost) indistinguishable from a normal host on the network